# A property of uniserial module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Recently I am working with exercises in The block theory of finite group algebras by Markus Linckelmann. I have a question about uniserial module. In Exercise 1.10.24, It says that

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra and $M$ a uniserial $A$-module. Show that $M$ is finitely generated and isomorphic to a quotient of the regular $A$-module $A$.

In this book $k$ represents a unital commutative ring and $A$ is always a finite dimension $k$-algebra that is  finitely generated as a $k$-module.

I want to construct a surjective map from $A$ to $M$ just as the proof of showing simple modules are regular, but I can't find such a map. How to construct this isomorphism? and do uniserial modules always have such a property?

Comment: $k$ a field or just a commutative ring?  It's certainly not true if $k$ can be $\mathbb Z$ and $M$ can be $\mathbb Z_{p^\infty}$.    I don't immediately have any other counterexamples at hand if $k$ has to be a field.  Another thing I would make sure of is if the authors only deal in finite dimensional algebras...

Comment: $k$ is a unital commutative ring and the author only deals in finite dimensional algebras.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, not all uniserial modules need be finitely generated, even under the conditions in the OP.  Let $A=k=\mathbb{Z}$, let $p$ be a prime, and let $M$ be the uniserial module $\mathbb{Z}_{p^\infty}$.  Certainly $M$ is not finitely generated.

There are positive results.  In fact, a nonzero uniserial module $M$ is cyclic if and only if it has a maximal submodule.  To see this, suppose $N$ is a maximal submodule and $m\in M\setminus N$.  Since $Rm$ is not contained in $N$, it must properly contain $N$, whence $M=Rm$.  Since every finitely generated nonzero module has maximal submodules, this shows that every finitely generated uniserial module is cyclic.

Let $J$ be the Jacobson radical of $A$ and suppose $J$ is nilpotent and $A/J$ is semisimple.  (Rings $A$ with these properties are called semiprimary.  Artinian rings are semiprimary.)  If $M$ is a nonzero uniserial module, the nilpotency of $J$ implies $JM\subsetneq M$.  As $M/JM$ is a nonzero semisimple module, it must have a maximal submodule.  Pulling this back, we see $M$ has a maximal submodule and thus $M$ is cyclic.

If $k$ is a commutative Artinian ring and $A$ is a $k$-algebra that is finitely generated as a $k$-module, then $A$ is Artinian.  Thus we get a positive answer to the OP: every uniserial $A$-module will be cyclic in this case.